# how to custom form errors in view

Tags: python, django

I am using this code to check how many images are being uploaded and the size of the image. Currently i am using a `ValidationError` but it looks like this in development

[image]

and in production is just throws a 500 server error. How can I have it throw a form error that looks something like this

[image: ![enter image description here]

I was using the messages framework as a work around but would much rather do it the proper way. Must be achieved in the view.

code:

```
if len(request.FILES.getlist('images')) > 3:
        #messages.error(request, 'More than 3 images')
        raise ValidationError(f'More than 3 images')

for image in request.FILES.getlist('images'):
    if image.size > settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE:
        raise ValidationError(f'Image {image} is too large 3mb max')
```

Comment: It is important in which context `ValidationError` is raised. Normally it is supposed to be used on the form and form fields level. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: @rootart Hey I read through Is it saying i shouldn't be throwing a form error as it is not related to the actual value of the field? If so what would you recommend as the best way to approach this

Comment: Hey @Wazy. If raised from the clean method of the form you will have it in the NON_FIELDS_ERROS https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.NON_FIELD_ERRORS. You can also attach errors to a specific field from the clean method using https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error and have expected representation.